# Import latest ionicons in webpack project

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webpack, sass, ionicons

Tried to import ionicons using several methods but didint work.

```
import ionicons from '../../node_modules/ionicons/dist/index'
```

in entry file of webpack doesn't work so does importing to css using :

```
$ionicons-font-path: "../../../node_modules/ionicons/fonts";
@import "~ionicons/scss/ionicons";
```

Want to import the latest version btw, not some 3 year old version.